# use fixed precision without trailing zeros

Tags: c++, string, printing, operating-system, precision

I'm using setPrecision and fixed so I can set the precision AFTER the decimal point, 
but I don't want to get something like this: 5.00000.
how can I take off the trailing zeros in an elegent way?
any specific way or should I perform string manipulations?

```
os << setprecision(5) << fixed << value;
```

Comment: Please add any-language OR platform for others to understand which language does this code involve! Please remove decimal tag and add language specific tag!!!

Comment: sorry, edited the tags

Answer (score -1):

Short Answer: Don't use fixed and instead set precision to whatever number you want + number of digits before decimal place.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Using `setprecision` will still result in scientific notation, which the OP wants to avoid.